# EPUB reader page curl like iBook

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to scroll the reader page like page curl in ibook.i used the following link to curl page in single page mode.[https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl][1]
But I want to do in iOS like android implementation as in the following link [https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl][2] i'm no familiar with android can anyone help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Apple Guide for supporting this feature.

Documentation on Paging:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

Alternatively, there is a third party resource for implementing this effect. Here is a link to their documentation:
http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/

Comment: i checked this link here also checked demo code but that is only horizontal sliding page animation. i need sir page curl like ibook and one more thing some apps also used uipageviewcontroller for pdf file but i'm using epub file to read if you have nay idea please help me thanks sir